# Pseint números aleatorios

Tags: matrices, pseint, vectores

Debo crear un ciclo que llene la matriz con números aleatorios entre 1o 30 azar(30)
La matriz tiene una dimensión de 4x4
Luego debo ordenarlos de menor a mayor

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ? Tal parece que estás pidiendo que alguien lo haga **para ti**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero declaras la matriz: `int[,] mat1 = new int[4,4];`
Luego realizas el ciclo para llenarla con los números aleatorios:

```
var rand = new Random();



for (int f = 0; f < mat1.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat1.GetLength(1); c++)
            {

                
                mat1[f, c] = rand.Next (1,30);
            }

        }
```

Y luego para ordenarlos puedes utilizar array.Sort, busca en la documentación de Microsoft sobre C#

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. En lo posible, evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad y que no demuestran esfuerzo por parte de quien formula la pregunta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y lee [answer].

Comment: Carlos es que debo hacerlo en pseint y la matriz tiene los números aleatorios azar , debo crear un algoritmo que los acomode de menor a mayor